# Android layout suggestion for videos/thumbnails with listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, video

I have one Android app to make. I am using Fragments. There will be one fragment which will be calling this video list. Now in this layout there will be videos (thumbnails) but the problem i am facing is before this list of thumbnails there will be one header for showing how many videos will be there and then again this same layout will repeat. For illustration here is the layout designed in paint.

[image: Wire-framed layout]

Now how can i achieve this when data is going to be loaded dynamically ?
I had a thought of using list view with title by adding those programatically. How should i go about this ?

And that thumbnail has to have buttons overlay.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make `Custom Layout` for `List View` and use it in `Base Adapter`.

Comment: what will custom layout have as inside? How can i put text and image combination when images are dynamic in number.

Comment: You have just an `Image View` `Text View` etc... Your stored data in `Array List` or what ever will fill data to it Dynamically.

Comment: But the images can be many. textviw will be one only. Thats title.

Comment: Just for reference check this https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

Comment: In that link all the row has similar structure but in my case 1st row is diff than others.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a layout in `xml` with `TextView` & the `ImageView` with overlay using `RelativeLayout`. Load this layout using `ListView`.

Make a model with all the necessary details. Add one `boolean` in the model which tells whether to show/hide the header in the `ListView` for this particular item.

In the `getView()` method,  check the `boolean` of the model and use like

```
headerText.setVisibility(model.getBool() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

So, if you should have 3 videos after first header and 7 videos after second header, your model should have `boolean` true for first element, then false for 2 elements, then true for 4th element and then false for 6 more elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds perfect. Let me try.

Comment: Man i tried it with diff concept. i am at run time adding layouts with one linear layout which has two text and one list view.